# How to update Outlook AppointmentItem using ICS with the right sequence number? I.e. how to determine sequence number?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, icalendar

I developed a Web Application which handles meeting data. Now I additionally developed a VSTO Outlook Plugin so that I can add a link to the meeting data on the web application to a given AppointmentItem in Outlook. For this, I use an API call to my web application by sending the UID (GlobalAppointmentID). But I couldn't find out how to also send the current sequence number when calling my web application's "Add-Method" of my API.

So we end up with 2 applications handling appointments one of which is Outlook.

In case the web application wants to send meeting updates to outlook it uses ICS files. The problem is that I didn't manage to send updates to the appointment from my web application to Outlook because I don't know which sequence number to use in the ICS file.

I cannot find any properties in AppointmehtItem which let me find out the current sequence number in Outlook. Also, I found out the using DTSTAMP instead of SEQUENCE does not solve the problem because updates using DTSTAMP are only allowed for updates which do not change the date/time of the appointment.

So my question is:
How can I find out the correct sequence number for an AppointmentItem so an external application can use it for sending updates using ICS files

My problem is that Outlook will probably send this sequence number when sending the invitation. In my case, my web application does not get invited, and thus it does not receive the sequence number from the invitation mail sent out by Outlook.

I assume that I try to solve the problem in a completely wrong way. Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After a few researches I think the whole concept of my Outlook Plugin is wrong.

From what I understand is that ICS Files are used so that Mail-Clients can communicate regarding events.

So one possible solution to my problem may be that the Web Application plays the role of a mail client receiving invitations from Outlook. Every change to an appointment will be issued from outlook to the web application as long as it is included with its own mailadress (info@mywebapplication.com) and the web application needs to parse the incoming requests, parse them and try to find out which meeting needs to be updated.

**May that be a solution? Has anyone experience in handling inbound meeting requests/updates/cancellations from Outlook, Google Calendar etc.? Does Outlook/Google use ICS for that? Probably yes, because the mail client cannot know which mail client the receiver uses, can it?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the master appointment with the exception in the same ICS file with the right `RECURRENCE-ID` header. Try to save a recurring appointment as an ICS file through the Outlook UI and open it in Notepad.

Comment: My question was not appoint recurring appointments. My question was how do I get the sequence number of my AppointmentItem so that I can send it to my web application. It has nothing to do with recurring appointments.